# Ruby Mail fetch without image parts

Tags: ruby, email

I'm fetching successfully a specific mail from uid identifier with this line of code:

```
msg = @mailbox.imap.uid_fetch(uid, ['RFC822','BODYSTRUCTURE', 'FLAGS', 'UID', 'RFC822.SIZE','BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO DATE SUBJECT MESSAGE-ID)]'])[0]
@mail = Mail.read_from_string msg.attr['RFC822']
```

The problem is that with RFC822 I get also parts image and it slow the entire process.

I want to get all message without all image parts?

How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by specifying the `BODY` with a part number to the `FETCH` command.

From the [`FETCH` specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.5):

> BODY[]<>

> The text of a particular body section.  The section
> specification is a set of zero or more part specifiers
> delimited by periods.  A part specifier is either a part number
> or one of the following: HEADER, HEADER.FIELDS,
> HEADER.FIELDS.NOT, MIME, and TEXT.  An empty section
> specification refers to the entire message, including the
> header.

So if the first part is text, we can use something like:

```
require 'net/imap'
imap = Net::IMAP.new 'mail.example.com', ssl:true
imap.authenticate 'LOGIN', 'user@example.com', "passwsord"

uid = 8465
imap.uid_fetch uid, 'BODY[1]'
```

And you can fetch multiple parts with something like:

```
imap.uid_fetch 8465, '(BODY[1] BODY[2.1])
```

You can get an overview of the message parts with the `BODYSTRUCTURE` command:

```
parts = imap.uid_fetch uid, 'BODYSTRUCTURE'
```

Multipart messages can be nested infinity, so you'll need a function to extract the text parts. Something like this seems to work:

```
def find_text_parts parts, parents='', text_parts
    parts.each.with_index do |part, i|
        if part.is_a? Net::IMAP::BodyTypeText
            text_parts << "#{parents}#{i + 1}"
        elsif part.is_a? Net::IMAP::BodyTypeMultipart
            p parents
            find_text_parts part.parts, "#{parents}#{i + 1}.", text_parts
        end
    end

    return text_parts
end
text_parts = find_text_parts parts[0].attr['BODYSTRUCTURE'].parts, '', []
```

And finally we send off the command to IMAP:

```
imap.uid_fetch 8465, "(#{text_parts.map { |p| "BODY[#{p}]" }.join(' ')})"
```